# Configure IntelliJ to look at a different directory when importing/requiring modules

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have an [AWS Lambda Application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/deploying-lambda-apps.html) with a lambda and a layer. The code for the layer is imported from the `/opt/` directory. So when I include the code in my project it looks like this.

```
// /opt/ folder doesn't exist
const someFunction = require("/opt/nodejs/someFunction");
```

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to look for `someFunction.js` in another folder instead of `/opt/nodejs`. Like alias `/opt/nodejs/someFunction` to `/actual/path/someFunction` within IntelliJ. I'm attempting to get intellisense and refactoring tools for functions that are imported from layers

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4414265426578-AWS-Lambda-with-Layer-Imports

Comment: @Oksana I asked there and a couple other places to see if they can update that plugin. I'm looking for a work around if they can't update the plugin.
https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/3020